# Forwarding port 80 to 8000 doesn't work

Tags: linux, networking

In order to avoid running a process as root I would like to run the server at port 8000 while routing all TCP packets coming in on port 80 to port 8000, and vice versa.

I use Arch Linux and made an *iptables reset* according to this [paragraph](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Iptables#Resetting_rules).

After that I ran the following command: `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp0s25 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8000` which is recommended everywhere. I got the `enp0s25` from my `ip -4 addr` output.

Now I have a nodejs server running on `0.0.0.0:8000` and make requests to my public IP. I get valid responses if I use this command: `curl xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:8000`. But I would like to achieve the same valid responses using `curl xxx.xxx.xxx.xx` and here I get the error `curl: (7) Failed to connect`.

Thank you!

Comment: You realize what port a service is running on has nothing to do with whether the process is running as root, right?

Comment: As far as I know only processes started as root can use port 80 on Linux, but I am new to this.

Comment: Right, ports <1024 must be bound by a process running as root. But a port >1024 can also be bound by a root process. Just checking your assumptions . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp0s25 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8000

reroutes traffic incoming to enp0s25 (the external facing interface), *not* to localhost. If you are running curl on the same box (localhost) it will only see 8000.

If you are accessing it remotely I would check that the host firewall is allowing incoming port 80

Comment: I am not running the server on the localhost, but I should have made this clear in OP. I run it on `0.0.0.0` and make requests to my public IP.

Comment: Answer expanded

Comment: Your emphasis of the word **remotely** made me check the connection from an external machine again and it works. I didn't test it before because I could make requests to port 8000 from the same machine successfully, so I didn't think that I had to use another machine to make requests to port 80. Could you maybe also give me a hint why this is happening differently? I will accept your answer after that. Thanks @Peleion !

Comment: remove the -i enp0s25 to enable nat on all interfaces. From man iptables regarding -i "If this option is omitted, any interface name will match."

Comment: Omitting the -i option didn't solve this.